# Most matching words in search query

Tags: mysql, search, full-text-search

I have user table (e.g. UserMst) is MySQL like

```
UserID  FirstName  LastName  FullName (expression column)   
------  ---------  --------  ----------------------------
1       Manish     Patel     Manish Patel
2       Dharmesh   Patel     Dharmesh Patel 
3       Patel      Pranay    Patel  Pranay
4       Patel      Ankita    Patel Ankita
```

Now I am fetching result as follows:

```
Select * from UserMst
where (    FirstName like 'patel dha%'
        OR LastName  like 'patel dha% 
        OR FullName  like '%patel dha% 
        OR FullName  like '%patel% 
        OR FullName  like '%dha% )
Order by ( case when FirstName like 'patel dha%' then 1
                WHEN LastName  like 'patel dha%' then 2 
                WHEN FirstName like '%patel dha' then 3
                WHEN LastName  like '%patel dha%'then 4 end ),
          FullName
```

This query return result perfect, but I need more nearest ordered result.
In this case If some one is enter keyword 'patel dha' (here user can leave more space between 2 words as well as he can type as many words too
e.g. 'patel    dha' or 'patel    dha pran')
it means
he is trying to find/search user 1 (e.g. Dharmesh patel)
This records should come first.

My expected result is: (If user enter this keyword: 'patel    dha' or 'patel dha')

```
UserID  FirstName  LastName  FullName   
------  ---------  --------  --------
2   Dharmesh   Patel     Dharmesh Patel 
4   Patel      Ankita    Patel Ankita
3   Patel      Pranay    Patel  Pranay
1   Manish     Patel     Manish Patel
```

If user search another way then
my expected result is: (If user enter this keyword: 'patel    dha pr' or 'patel dha pran')

```
UserID  FirstName  LastName  FullName   
------  ---------  --------  --------
2   Dharmesh   Patel     Dharmesh Patel 
3   Patel      Pranay    Patel  Pranay
4   Patel      Ankita    Patel Ankita
1   Manish     Patel     Manish Patel
```

Order changed. (Because most matching words found)

Can we use here regular expression? Or maybe another way to do this?

Comment: Use fulltext search indexing for that: http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/

Comment: thanks @AlmaDoMundo, can you please give me some example? and one more thing, result returns perfect, but problem is just ordering.

Comment: Why don't you want to follow the link for the example?

Comment: @YourCommonSense, I am trying to do. but I have doubt that he is not understand my question. that's why I am just explaining him in more detail.

Comment: fulltext index is exactly what you want. But it is not something simple you can kick in with simple move. One have to read the documentation to have any profit from it.

Comment: ya that's true. anyway many thanks for reply @YourCommonSense

Comment: Hi @AlmaDoMundo, I have tried what you suggest. but strange, In my result, score returns the same value. I have followed exactly same as your link mentioned. so, I can't figer out where is the problem is? let me explain, first I had altered my table for FULLTEXT (FirstName, LastName) and then append one column in my query is "MATCH(FirstName, LastName) AGAINST ('patel dha') As Score". Is is ok? my table engine is "Innodb" and my records are already inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it works as you said, just that in first example Manish Patel should be ranked 2 because of the Sort order A-Z.

Maybe I didn't get the question fully though :)

[Here is a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ed0e/5)

EDIT: by the way the entry with the 2 spaces I changed to underscores, since it seemed that SQLFiddle is auto trimming duplicates.